# In $ℤ/Nℤ$, which units are successors to zero divisors?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, ring-theory

What are the units $x$ in $ℤ/Nℤ$ of the form $x = 1 + \overline{kd}$ for a divisor $d$ of $N$ and $k ∈ ℤ$, i.e.
$$U_N[d] := \{x ∈ (ℤ/Nℤ)^×;\; ∃ k ∈ ℤ : x = 1 + \overline{kd}\} = \ker \big((ℤ/Nℤ)^× → (ℤ/dℤ)^×\big)?$$

- How many such units are there?
- How (else) do they look like?

---

The following is a wrong formulation and needs to be fixed:

> Now, let $π_e$ denote the projection $ℤ/Nℤ → ℤ/eℤ$ for divisors $e$ of $N$. Then $U_N[d] = \ker π_d$.
>   What I really want to know is:
>
> - Is $π_{N/d}(\ker{π_d})$ bijectively related to the units in $ℤ/(d,N/d)ℤ$?

Comment: To form the quotient $\,\Bbb Z/\Bbb N\,$ , what *algebraic structure* are you working with? Or you did mean $\,\Bbb Z/N\Bbb Z\,$ ?

Comment: @DonAntonio Yes, I meant $ℤ/Nℤ$, the ordinary quotients of $ℤ$ by ideals $Nℤ ⊂ ℤ$.